# "comments must be at least 15 characters in length" when I am trying to post a question

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, comments, new-users, character-limit

I have been trying to post a question on Stack Overflow for the first time. My title and body meet the minimum character requirements, but when I try to post it, I get "*Comments must be at least 15 characters in length*" and won't let me post.

I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Staff are looking into this according to the [MSO duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416870/6083675).

Comment: @Laurel just curious, what gives you the impression staff looking into it? Adding status review only means it's added to a TODO list with thousands of other bugs and requests. It's not even "planned", which means "We are aware it's a bug and working on a fix". Unless staff actually says "We're looking into it", well, I won't expect them to really do it.

Comment: @Shadow While there is a backlog of tagged posts like that, this is a critical bug because it's preventing people from posting, likely a lot more than the 3 I saw who reported it today. That's the type of bug that I see getting fixed the fastest.

Comment: @Laurel hope you're correct.

Comment: The duplicate does not answer the question (comments can be deleted at any time).

Comment: @Shadow FWIW, they fixed it.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum totally not relevant. The bug was not with comments, it's with questions that can't be submitted. Error message from the server was just plain wrong and confusing, it has nothing to do with comments. Duplicate reports exactly the same bug.